# Pass subclass of generic model to razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, oop, razor

**The Big Picture:**

I have found what seems like a limitation of Razor and I am having trouble coming up with a good way around it.

**The Players:**

Let's say I have a model like this:

```
public abstract class BaseFooModel<T>
    where T : BaseBarType
{
    public abstract string Title { get; } // ACCESSED BY VIEW
    public abstract Table<T> BuildTable();

    protected Table<T> _Table;
    public Table<T> Table // ACCESSED BY VIEW
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Table == null)
            {
                _Table = BuildTable();
            }
            return _Table;
        }
    }
}
```

And a subclass like this:

```
public class MyFooModel : BaseFooModel<MyBarType>
{
    // ...
}

public class MyBarType : BaseBarType
{
    // ...
}
```

I want to be able to pass `MyFooModel` into a razor view that is defined like this:

```
// FooView.cshtml
@model BaseFooModel<BaseBarType>
```

But, that doesn't work. I get a run-time error saying that `FooView` expects `BaseFooModel<BaseBarType>` but gets `MyFooModel`. Recall that `MyFooModel` in herits from `BaseFooModel<MyBarType>` and `MyBarType` inherits from `BaseBarType`.

**What I have tried:**

I tried this out in non-razor land to see if the same is true, which it is. I had to use a template param in the View to get it to work. Here is that non-razor view:

```
public class FooView<T>
    where T : BaseBarType
{
    BaseFooModel<T> Model;
    public FooView(BaseFooModel<T> model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }
}
```

With that structure, the following **does work**:

```
new FooView<MyBarType>(new MyFooModel());
```

**My Question:**

**How can I do that with Razor?** How can I pass in a type like I am doing with `FooView`?
**I can't**, but is there any way around this? Can I achieve the same architecture somehow?

Let me know if I can provide more info. I'm using .NET 4 and MVC 3.

---

**EDIT:**
For now, I am just adding a razor view for each subclass of `BaseFooModel<BaseBarType>`. I'm not psyched about that because I don't want to have to create a new view every time I add a new model.

The other option is to just take advantage of the fact that I *am* able to get this working in regular c# classes without razor. I could just have my razor view `@inherits` the c# view and then call some render method. I dislike that option because I don't like having two ways of rendering html.

Any other ideas? I know its hard to understand the context of the problem when I'm giving class names with `Foo` and `Bar`, but I can't provide too much info since it is a bit sensitive. My apologies about that.

---

**What I have so far, using Benjamin's answer:**

```
public interface IFooModel<out T> 
    where T : BaseBarModel
{
    string Title { get; }
    Table<T> Table { get; } // this causes an error:
                            // Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be 
                            // invariantly valid on IFooModel<T>.Table. 
                            // 'T' is covariant.
}

public abstract class BaseFooModel<T> : IFooModel<T>
    where T : BaseBarModel
{
    // ...
}
```

**What ended up working:**

```
public interface IFooModel<out T> 
    where T : BaseBarModel
{
    string Title { get; }
    BaseModule Table { get; } // Table<T> inherits from BaseModule
                              // And I only need methods from BaseModule
                              // in my view. 
}

public abstract class BaseFooModel<T> : IFooModel<T>
    where T : BaseBarModel
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: quite often I find an answer by the time I've typed up the question or at least shortly after. not this time...

Comment: what's your BaseFooModel - and what does it do on the page (inserts, just viewing, is it changed etc.)? that's relevant (some example code)

Comment: This is a good point but I would argue that as this information is being used in a view it should only be getting read. Any updates should be happening in a controller action method.

Comment: @NSGaga to answer your question, see Benjamin's comment above. He is right. Just some getters and methods that subclasses must implement.

Comment: @Benjamin your comment is even better :) I think (makes sense) - and the answer is worth of bounty - but I'm looking if we could improve on that. i.e. the details make the whole difference with 'variance'. `IEnumerable<Record>` would do for simple cases (of course no 'header' etc.). If base interface has to support anything - or via js or something - then that might fall through.

Comment: @lbstr - I think it's best you try out the Benjamin's solution - as long as the interface is `readonly` (a bit simplified) - that should work

Comment: @NSGaga I added more info to my definition of `BaseFooModel` above. Both items that are accessed by the view are getters only, so Ben's answer should still be good right?

Comment: if it works it works :) Benjamin's answer is as I'd write it - there are just limitations (e.g. Table<T>) - and that can be worked around by reorganizing usually. Just post an update on this if you don't mind - if it turns out complicated - I'd like to know for my own sake.

Comment: @NSGaga check out my comment under Ben's answer...

Comment: @lbstr thx - for me to be able to help anything (post an answer that significantly differs from Ben's) I'd need the whole structure/classes (the significant parts - but w/ variance that goes down and is almost the whole thing)

Comment: NSGaga has a good point. My answer gets you started although there are a number of further design decisions to be made based on your actual needs which can't really be answered without seeing the **actual** code (although I'd argue this is outside the scope of this question).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to introduce an interface with a [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd469487.aspx) generic type parameter into your class hierarchy:

```
public interface IFooModel<out T> where T : BaseBarType
{
}
```

And derive your BaseFooModel from the above interface.

```
public abstract class BaseFooModel<T> : IFooModel<T> where T : BaseBarType
{
}
```

In your controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new MyFooModel());
}
```

Finally, update your view's model parameter to be:

```
@model IFooModel<BaseBarType>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! This is working very well so far. I'll hang on before accepting until I'm sure that it will work in my situation. +1

Comment: Great to hear that! I had a similar problem in my code so I'm glad I was able to use this to help someone else out. If you come across any problems please post some more information and I will try to help if I can.

Comment: +1 I wasn't trying to undermine you - I'm not that hungry - as e.g. Jon is :)

Comment: I updated my question with more details on what is inside `BaseFooModel`. I moved `string Title` and `Table<T> Table` up to the interface since they are accessed by the view. I am getting now getting an Invalid variance error ('T' must be invariantly valid on `IFooModel<T>.Table`). Could you please explain why that is? What could T be that would make that invalid?

Comment: Your interface is covariant so has to be read only. Ensure the interface only has read only properties (getters but no setters) and no methods that accept a parameter of type T. Your parameters also have to be read-only if they use the T parameter.

Comment: I just updated my post again. At the very bottom, you'll see what I'm working with right now. `Table<T> Table` is read only.

Comment: You are basically experiencing the same problem all over again. The `Table<T>` class will need to have an interface with a covariant type parameter for it to work (or move it back to your `BaseFooModel` class!).

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I ended up replacing `Table<T>` with a class that is higher up in the inheritance chain. This was a great learning experience for me.

Comment: Good... grief... it works! Please pass on my thanks to your 2013 self for saving me from 2018 Razor insanity. Once you start down the generic rabbit hole there's no way back!

Answer (score 2):

Using interfaces-based models was deliberately changed between ASP.NET MVC 2 and MVC 3.

[You can see here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636341/modelmetadata-fromlambdaexpression-has-changed-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rtm)

MVC Team:

Having interface-based models is not something we encourage (nor, given the limitations imposed by the bug fix, can realistically support). Switching to abstract base classes would fix the issue.

"Scott Hanselman"

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is not a Razor error, but a C# error.  Try to do that with classes, and you'll get the same error.  This is because the model is not `BaseFooModel<BaseBarType>`, but `BaseFooModel<MyFooModel>`, and an implicit conversion cannot happen between the two.  Normally, in a program you'd have to do a conversion to do that.

However, with .NET 4, introduced was [contravariance and covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx), which sounds like the ability of what you are looking for.  This is a .NET 4 feature only, and I honestly don't know if Razor in .NET 4 makes use of it or not.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Brian. You're right; I did see the same thing with classes, which is what I tried to explain above with the `FooView<T>` bit. Adding a template param was the only way I could get it to work, which obviously doesn't translate to Razor. Can you explain what you meant when you said that the list is not `IEnumerable<BaseBarType>`, but `IEnumerable<MyFooModel>`. What list?

Comment: what `IEnumerable`? The model should just be a single `MyFooModel`, not a collection.

Comment: Err, I am really off, I meant BaseFooModel, so I updated by post above.

Comment: Both views (razor and `FooView`) are setup to receive `BaseFooModel<BaseBarType>` as a model. In both cases, I am passing `MyFooModel`, which is a `BaseFooModel<MyBarType>`. It seems like the only way that works is if I pass `MyBarType` as a template param to the View. But, since I can't define a template param on a razor view I am stuck.

Comment: Right your Razor view can't be that flexible to use the BaseBarType, you have to use MyBarType without contravariance and covariance implicit conversion in .NET 4 (and even then, I don't know if that would even work).  That's an unfortunate limitation.